# output after git checkout

Tags: git

After checking out a branch in a repository git always prints a list of roughly 25 files that were deleted long ago. I always just ignored that output but recently I had to do a hard reset, which I assumed would just go back to the last commit, which it did but it also restored those 25 files. Is there some way of removing those files from git? I tried git rm but since they were long deleted that didn't work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you deleted the files from your directory, but never committed the deletions (like Bombe said, with `git rm`). That's why they came back after the `git reset`.

Deleting a file is just like any other change, it has to be recorded in the repository (which is what `git rm [file]` will do).

Comment: Just to be clear. After I've made some changes I usually do the following: "git add .", then "git commit -m "change made"". If I deleted a file should I then type: "git rm .", then "git commit -m "removed file"". Or will "git rm ." just remove everything (even files that were not deleted?).

Comment: Yeah, I made that mistake - "git rm ." will removing everything. My current workflow is to use `git commit -a -m 'Commit message'`, which will stage *all* of the changes you've made, with the exception of untracked files (which you'll still need to do `git add <path>` on).

Comment: so the -a option gets rid of the need to use "git add ." and "git rm ."?

Comment: Correct, but only with regard to tracked files. From the Manual (Git-Commit):

"OPTIONS: -a, -all: Tell the command to automatically stage files that have been modified and deleted, but new files you have not told git about are not affected."

Answer (score 1):

If they were deleted Git wouldn’t restore them upon a `git reset --hard` so `git rm` should indeed be the correct way to get rid of them. (Don’t forget  to commit afterwards!)

You might want to take a look at what Git thinks has happened with these files. `git log path/to/file` might help you there.

Other things to check are:

- are you on the correct branch? `gitk --all` will give you a nice overview of all your branches, including the ability to search for changes to a specific file only.
- are you on the correct repository? If you have multiple checkouts of your repository all over your harddriver you might simply be looking at an old one.
- maybe someone has added these files again? Again, check the commit logs using `git log`.

Comment: When I type git log:
master $ git log app/views/participants/index.html.erb
fatal: ambiguous argument 'app/views/participants/index.html.erb': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.

Yet that is one of the files that keeps on appearing with a 'D' next to it when I checkout. 

I believe that those files were deleted normally, without the help of git, could that be the problem?